# Order by subclass-property in JPA InheritanceType.JOINED Tables

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using JPA with EclipseLink and a `InheritanceType.JOINED` Structure:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="PARENT")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE")
public abstract class Parent { ... }

@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD_A")
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class ChildA extends Parent { ... }

@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD_B")
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class ChildB extends Parent { ... }
```

If I use Criteria-API to query data of the type `Parent.class`, the resulting SQL Statment looks like

```
SELECT t0.ID, ..., t1.ID, ..., t2.ID FROM 
PARENT t0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILD_A t1 ON (t1.ID = t0.ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILD_B t2 ON (t2.ID = t0.ID) 
WHERE ... 
ORDER BY t0.PROPERTY ASC
```

Maybe it is a silly question, but is there any possibility to use a joined property (from CHILD_A or CHILD_B) in the ORDER clause via Criteria-API?

I did the following:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Parent> q = cb.createQuery(Parent.class);
Root<Parent> c = q.from(Parent.class);

// FIXME: Don't know how to add orderBy of subclass property

TypedQuery<Parent> query = em.createQuery(q);
return query.getResultList();
```

Can anyone tell me, if this is the right approach to do the ordering and how it is done?